# Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/core/Breadcrumbs'

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I am using React **Material ui**.Tried to use [BreadCrump](https://material-ui.com/components/breadcrumbs/) component of Material UI.
But while using this i got the following error.

*Can't resolve '@material-ui/core/Breadcrumbs'*.

I have already installed @material-ui/core in my application as well.

> "@material-ui/core": "^3.9.3"

Not sure why this issue happens.Is there any issue with the @material-ui/core version i am using ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the latest version.

Version **4.6.1**  Solve the problem.